# How use a print statement from a defined function in Python

Tags: python, function, printing

How can I call this defined function with customized text before each animation, so i can just print it like `print(Anim("text"))`?

```
import time
import sys

animation = "|/-\\"

def Anim(text):
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write("\r" + animation[i % len(animation)])
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Make `Anim` return the thing to be printed

Comment: @James Windows 10

Comment: @rdas Yes but how? I'm struggling a bit because the format doesn't fit right or the error message says there are to many arguments used

Comment: Something like `sys.stdout.write(f"\r{text}" + animation[i % len(animation)])`?

Comment: @Matthias Yes perfect. Can you explain me what the " f " does there?

Comment: [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer:** thanks to [@Matthias](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209921/matthias)

```
sys.stdout.write(f"\r{text}" + animation[i % len(animation)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import time

animation = "|/-\\"

def Anim(text):
    for i in range(20):
        time.sleep(0.1)
        yield "\r" + animation[i % len(animation)]

for frame in Anim(animation):
    print(frame, flush=True, end="")
```

Comment: Yes but with a singe print statement, just like print(Anim("text")). So I don't get how to implement the text there. Edit: @Matthias answer works well